# npm path keeps defaulting to /usr/local/bin/npm

Tags: command-line, npm

Every few days all of my dependencies stop working, and I need to run

`export PATH="$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH"`

in order to restore all of my commands. I'm pretty new to using npm, is this normal? If not, is there a way I can make it so this doesn't happen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's else inside your Path? echo $PATH

Comment: ```/Users/quinnlangille/.node_modules_global/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin``` is what terminal outputs